# Installing Oracle 11gR2 on Oracle Linux 6 - error possibly related to database (unique) name

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, linux, installation

Installing 11gR2 on Oracle Linux 6.4. System is a desktop used by one developer. It's on DHCP. Hostname is similar to ip-t3400-1547.mydomain.local

Please note I have no issues installing this software on systems with fixed IP address, where the hostname is a solid alphanumeric string (no dashes).

I am loosely following:

- [Oracle® Database Quick Installation Guide 11g Release 2 (11.2) for Linux x86-64 E10860-01 August 2009](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14075_01/doc/install.112/e10860.pdf)
- [Oracle Database 11g Release 2 on Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6 Deployment Recommendations Version 1.1 March 2012](http://jp.redhat.com/rhecm/rest-rhecm/jcr/repository/collaboration/jcr:system/jcr:versionStorage/a0fd0c8e0a05260205ec44ea6c61f396/3/jcr:frozenNode/rh:resourceFile)

I've installed the package oracle-rdbms-server-11gR2-preinstall, which takes care of many pre-install tasks. I've set SELinux to permissive. Quote from /home/oracle/.bash_profile:

```
export ORACLE_BASE=/u01/app/oracle
export ORACLE_SID=joe
export ORACLE_UNQNAME=joe
export ORACLE_HOSTNAME=ip-t3400-1547
umask 022
```

"joe" is the owner of the machine, so I'm using his name as the SID (real name edited for privacy). Please note that everything described below happens with or without ORACLE_UNQNAME being set here.

I select Server Class, Single Instance, Advanced Install, Enterprise Edition, General Purpose configuration type, then:

```
Global database name: joe
Oracle Service Identifier: joe
```

**The above parameters, and the variables in .bash_profile, are different when installing on a system with a fixed IP address. In that case, I set ORACLE_HOSTNAME to the actual hostname of the machine (e.g.: dbserver13.mydomain.local), ORACLE_UNQNAME to the hostname (dbserver13), and SID same as UNQNAME (dbserver13). Works great.**

**I cannot do that on the DHCP-based workstation, because our naming convention includes the dash character in the hostname, which is not accepted by the installer for all those parameters.**

**I believe this difference is what causes the installer to fail, but I can't figure out an alternative.**

I have tried to add "joe" and "joe.mydomain.local" to /etc/hosts, on the loopback entry (beginning with 127.0.0.1) but it makes no difference.

Character Sets: Unicode. Select Use Database Control, notifications disabled.

Some pre-requisite packages fail the check, but this is fine.

The installer keeps chugging along, then towards the end it throws this warning:

[image]

```
Enterprise manager configuration succeeded with the following warning -

Error starting Database Control. Please execute the following command(s).

1) Set the enrvironment variable ORACLE_UNQNAME to Database unique name

2) /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/bin/emctl start dbconsole
```

The problem is, I have that variable set already. It makes no difference.

As a result, the installer only asks me to run one post-install script, instead of the usual two scripts. The Web UI doesn't seem to work.

I am obviously doing something wrong.

How should I choose all those database names and SIDs and whatnot, in a way that allows me to install 11gR2 on a DHCP-based desktop?

Comment: What is the result of `ping "$ORACLE_HOSTNAME"` command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must edit bash-profile then install oracle database .
in that you can set oracle_home and oracle_sid and etc .
i have similar mistake and resolve it with edit bash-profile in oracle user to real and correct values 
at the end , you can refer to this article , it is useful

http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/11g/oracle-db-11gr2-installation-on-oracle-linux-6.php

Comment: Right, that one would work. I've found an algorithm meanwhile that works 100%, and mine even works on systems on DHCP, with a changing IP and hostname. It's pretty similar to the one you've linked, with some extra twists.